# Make JavaScript helper function to match text against the regex dynamically

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to create a JavaScript helper function that will match the string and regex dynamically.

```
   //Helper function
    function is_mask(str, regax){
        mask = new RegExp(regax, 'i');
        return mask.test( str );
    }
```

So that's the helper function now if I want to call that function I' ll be doing something like this

```
is_mask('text', 'a-zA-Z'); //Should return true
```

My result is always false. What am I doing wrong over here?

Comment: `a-zA-Z` should be wrapped with `[]`..`is_mask('text', '[a-zA-Z]')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is checking the regexp against the entire "str". So, the call you are looking for is more like this.

```
> is_mask('text', '[a-zA-Z]+');
true
```